# File Explorer - Altering File/Folder associated icon programmatically

Tags: java, filesystems, system-tray, jdic

Have you noticed modifications to the icons associated with files and folders when using file explorer in windows/linux while having a svn client installed (e.g., TortoiseSVN). Basically, when a folder is saved in a SVN repository, normally there is a tiny green tick icon added to the associated file icon. I want to know how TortoiseSVN/Dropbox/... do this and whether I can achieve similar results using Java6 JDIC ?

Thanks,
-A

Answer (score 2):

Those are called "icon overlays" in Shell jargon. Here's a start:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144123(v=VS.85).aspx

-scott

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out..
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/jdic_assoc/

> - org.jdesktop.jdic.filetypes.Association
>
>   The Association class allows
>     programmers to create new file types
>     or edit existing ones. The class
>     includes methods to edit the file
>     extension type, the MIME extension
>     type, the icon that goes with the file
>     type, and the actions that are
>     associated with the file type.associated with the file type.